# Is there are more efficient method for creating a dictionary of letters mapped to letters shifted by a set integer?

Tags: python, performance, dictionary, coding-efficiency

I have written a function which takes an integer and returns a dictionary where the letters of the alphabet are mapped to an alphabet shifted by the integer. It has the requirement that lowercase and uppercase letters must correpsond, that is if a -> b then A->B.

I'm fairly new to python and have little experience with creating lists so I'm just wondering if there is an alternative more efficient or even just more elegant way to complete the same outcome.

```
import string

dictionary = []

for letter in string.ascii_lowercase + string.ascii_uppercase:
    dictionary.append(letter)
    
   

def build_shift(shift):
    
    shifted_dictionary = []
    
    for i in range(0,26):
        shifted_dictionary.append(dictionary[(i + shift) % 26])
        
    for i in range(26, 53):
        shifted_dictionary.append(dictionary[(( i + shift) % 26) + 26])
        
    return (shifted_dictionary)    
 
    
mapped_dictionary = dict( zip(dictionary, build_shift(2)))  

print(mapped_dictionary)
```

Comment: I'm not an obsessive code optimizer, so I'll let others answer the question of code optimization. As a general comment though, I would recommend against calling a list a dictionary because a dictionary is a completely separate data structure from a list - you will only confuse the person reading your code down the line (and that person will probably be yourself).

Comment: oh i see what you mean, it was just this case, I guess alphabet would be more suitable and less confusing

Answer (score 1):

You can use a dict comprehension that iterates characters over each of the lowercase and uppercase strings to output the character mapped to the one at the current index plus the offset and reduced with a modulo of 26. Below is an example using 2 as the offset:

```
{
    c: s[(i + 2) % 26]
    for s in (string.ascii_lowercase, string.ascii_uppercase)
    for i, c in enumerate(s)
}
```

Comment: The difficulty is that if I just reduce modulo 26, or even 52, I would get the Upper Case ones mapped to lower case with certain shifts. A shift of 2 would map "Z" to "b", but a requirement is that it goes to "B". I couldn't figure out how to do this without treating the cases of lower and upper case separately, is it possible to do this with your method?

Comment: That's what `for s in (string.ascii_lowercase, string.ascii_uppercase)` is for. By looping through the strings separately instead of joining them first it does exactly what you want. Please see demo: https://repl.it/@blhsing/TriflingIrresponsibleEvents

Answer (score 0):

You can slice the string and get the desired result in less number of operations.

```py
import string
shift = 2
changed_lc = f'{string.ascii_lowercase[shift:]}{string.ascii_lowercase[:shift]}'
changed_up = f'{string.ascii_uppercase[shift:]}{string.ascii_uppercase[:shift]}'
changed = f'{changed_lc}{changed_up}'
mapped_dictionary = dict(zip(string.ascii_letters, changed))
print(mapped_dictionary)
```

**output:**
{'a': 'c', 'b': 'd', 'c': 'e', 'd': 'f', 'e': 'g', 'f': 'h', 'g': 'i', 'h': 'j', 'i': 'k', 'j': 'l', 'k': 'm', 'l': 'n', 'm': 'o', 'n': 'p', 'o': 'q', 'p': 'r', 'q': 's', 'r': 't', 's': 'u', 't': 'v', 'u': 'w', 'v': 'x', 'w': 'y', 'x': 'z', 'y': 'a', 'z': 'b', 'A': 'C', 'B': 'D', 'C': 'E', 'D': 'F', 'E': 'G', 'F': 'H', 'G': 'I', 'H': 'J', 'I': 'K', 'J': 'L', 'K': 'M', 'L': 'N', 'M': 'O', 'N': 'P', 'O': 'Q', 'P': 'R', 'Q': 'S', 'R': 'T', 'S': 'U', 'T': 'V', 'U': 'W', 'V': 'X', 'W': 'Y', 'X': 'Z', 'Y': 'A', 'Z': 'B'}

Comment: thanks, I'll have to review the commands, not familiar with the f'{} one,

Comment: You can refer some examples of f-strings [here](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/formatted-string-literals-f-strings-in-python)